# How to de-dup by a group of rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table called 'inventory' where for each day, I list each item and its quantity.

```
inventory
---------------------
day | item | quantity
1    Apples   5
1    Oranges  3
2    Apples   5
2    Oranges  3
3    Apples   5
3    Oranges  3
3    Peaches  8
4    Apples   5
4    Oranges  3
4    Peaches  8
5    Apples   2
5    Oranges  3
5    Peaches  8
```

By de-duping, I want to get rid of any day which has the exact same data as the day before.  So the resulting table should look like this:

```
inventory
---------------------
day | item | quantity
1    Apples   5
1    Oranges  3
3    Apples   5
3    Oranges  3
3    Peaches  8
5    Apples   2
5    Oranges  3
5    Peaches  8
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Your desired results include "3, Apples, 5". Should that row (and some others) be in your desired results? Because there is another row "2, Apples, 5" for the previous day.

Comment: yes it should.  Because day 3 has changes, EVERY ROW from day 3 should be in the resultset.

Comment: Question was changed by the OP after some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider some missing days, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  i.day, i.item, i.quantity
FROM (
  SELECT t1.day, t1.item, t1.quantity, MAX(t2.day) as prec_day
  FROM
    inventory t1 LEFT JOIN inventory t2
    ON t1.item=t2.item AND t1.day>t2.day
  GROUP BY
    t1.day, t1.item, t1.quantity) i
  LEFT JOIN inventory i2
  ON i.item=i2.item AND i.prec_day=i2.day
WHERE
  i2.day IS NULL or i.quantity<>i2.quantity
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee76/1).

**EDIT:** if you need to show all items whenever there's at least one change, you could use this:

```
SELECT
  inventory.*
FROM
  inventory
WHERE
  day IN (
    SELECT
      i.day
    FROM (
      SELECT t1.day, t1.item, t1.quantity, MAX(t2.day) as prec_day
      FROM
        inventory t1 LEFT JOIN inventory t2
        ON t1.item=t2.item AND t1.day>t2.day
      GROUP BY
        t1.day, t1.item, t1.quantity) i
      LEFT JOIN inventory i2
      ON i.item=i2.item AND i.prec_day=i2.day
    WHERE
      i2.day IS NULL or i.quantity<>i2.quantity)
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee76/9).

Comment: that looks correct, although now I'm trying to figure out how this works so that I can apply it to my actual problem (which is a bit more complex).  thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like:

```
Select day, (Select Item, Quantity From tables Where Criteria) From tables Where Criteria Group By Day.
```

May work

Answer (score 0):

The following solution makes use of a coordinated sub-select.

```
select day, item, quantity
from yourTable t
where quantity <> ( select quantity from yourTable y where y.day = t.day - 1 and y.item = t.item )
```

Tested it and it works, at least as I understood the question.

Comment: hmm, this works if I have data on every single day.  There might be days where I'm missing data.  So, if day 7 and day 8 are missing, day 9 should check against day 6 to see if it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to find inventory items that are identical to the day before, and exclude them in the `WHERE` clause. Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13623/1).

```
SELECT
   inv.day
  ,inv.item
  ,inv.quantity
FROM inventory AS inv
LEFT JOIN inventory AS prev_day
  ON prev_day.day = inv.day - 1
  AND prev_day.item = inv.item
  AND prev_day.quantity = inv.quantity
WHERE prev_day.day IS NULL
```

Comment: The only problem is that I'm trying to de-dup DAY BY DAY, not Row by Row.  Notice the difference between your result-set and the result-set that I want.